# How to get cluster for 1D data?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a csv file which looks like below

```
page    Page_Value  
page1   12
page2   1   
page3   2   
page4   3   
page5   10
page6   11
page7   13
page8   67
page9   70
```

```
#covert page to numeric
labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
labelEncoder.fit(dataset_PV['page'])
dataset_PV['page'] = labelEncoder.transform(dataset_PV['page'])

#find out no. of cluster using elbow methos
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import preprocessing
wcss = []
for i in range(1,10):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(dataset_PV)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.plot(range(1,10), wcss,marker='o')
plt.title('Elbow graph')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('within-cluster sums of squares (WCSS)')
plt.show()

#fit model
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='k-means++', random_state=42)
clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(dataset_PV)
dataset_PV['clusters'] = clusters
```

**I want to create combination of pages based on Page Value to get maximum of Page values**. Here I have used K-means for which I have converted page variable to numeric. I am not sure if I should use k-means or sort the Page_value variable and then group them(not sure about the code).

**Output something like this:**

```
  Cluster1 = page2,page3,page4
  Cluster2 = page5,page6,page7,page12
  Cluster3 = page7,page8,page9
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to sort pages first. Have you tried Opencv K-mean? I hope it helps.
[https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d5c/tutorial_py_kmeans_opencv.html]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

pages = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8', 'p9']
x = np.array((12,1,2,3,10,11,13,67,70))
x = np.float32(x)
x = np.reshape(x, (-1,1))

# Define criteria = ( type, max_iter = 10 , epsilon = 1.0 )
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)

# Set flags (Just to avoid line break in the code)
flags = cv.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS
K = 3

# Apply KMeans
compactness, labels, centers = cv.kmeans(x, K, None, criteria, 10, flags)

labels = labels.flatten()

# result
res = dict()
for i in range(K):
    res[i] = []

for idx, lab in enumerate(labels):
    res[lab].append(pages[idx])

print(res)
```

Another solution using Sklearn:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

pages = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8', 'p9']
x = np.array((12,1,2,3,10,11,13,67,70))
x = np.float32(x)
x = np.reshape(x, (-1,1))

K=3
km = KMeans(n_clusters=K)
km.fit(x)
labels = km.predict(x)
labels = labels.flatten()

# result
res = dict()
for i in range(K):
    res[i] = []

for idx, lab in enumerate(labels):
    res[lab].append(pages[idx])

print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks Son! I have updated my question to make it more clear though the above link is quite confusing to use for a beginner like me.

Comment: initially, you know the exact number of clusters, right?

Comment: error: no module named cv2.
Any other module that we can use since I can see a lot of questions for Cv2 not supporting in Colab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215723/discussion-between-sahay-and-sn-ninh).

Answer (score 2):

You have done most of the work, but the name of the page should not be included in the calculation of `KMeans`, that makes no sense.

i.e. LabelEncoder is not necessary

tl;Dr

> The short answers you can refer to @Sơn Ninh.

If you want to visualization my answer may help you.

I write a function (`label_encoding`) for you, and you can use it to get the mapping of id that helps to draw pictures.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd
import textwrap
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from typing import Union, NamedTuple
from collections import defaultdict


def main():
    df = import_file()
    suitable_n: int
    x = df.Page_Value.values.reshape(-1, 1)
    if not 'Use the Elbow method to get a suitable N.':
        # You can omit this if you don't want to see it at all.
        elbow_find_n(x)
    suitable_n = 3

    # fit model
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=suitable_n, init='k-means++', random_state=42)
    clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(x)

    # labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
    # labelEncoder.fit(df['page'])
    # df['page'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['page'])
    df.loc[:, ['page']], mapping_table = label_encoding(df.loc[:, ['page']])
    df = rebuild_df(df, clusters, mapping_table)  # 'page-id', 'page', 'Page_Value', 'clusters'
    print(df)

    dict_by_cluster_value = defaultdict(list)
    for cur_set in set(df['clusters']):  # Output the format that you define.
        print(f'Cluster{cur_set} = {",".join(df.page[df.clusters == cur_set])}')
        dict_by_cluster_value[cur_set].extend(df.page[df.clusters == cur_set].to_list())
    print(dict(dict_by_cluster_value))  # it's ok with defaultdict, I convert the type is for print beautiful.
    visualizing_the_clusters(kmeans, df)


class RGBColor(NamedTuple):
    BLACK = '#000000'
    # AZURE = '#F0FFFF'
    OLIVE = '#808000'
    PINK = '#FFC0CB'
    # WHITE = '#000000'  <-- not suitable put it on background is white.
    GOLD = 'FFD700'
    BLUE = '#0000FF'
    GREEN = '#00FF00'
    RED = '#FF0000'
    YELLOW = '#FFFF00'
    ORANGE = '#FFA500'
    PURPLE = '#FF00FF'

    def get_tuple(self):
        return (attr_name for attr_name in dir(self) if not attr_name.startswith('_') and attr_name.isupper())


def label_encoding(label_col: Union[pd.DataFrame, np.ndarray], is_need_mapping_table=True) -> tuple:
    """
    USAGE:
    df.loc[:, ['col_xxx', ]], mapping_table = label_encoding(df.loc[:, ['col_xxx']])
    """
    nda_rtn_value = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(label_col.values.ravel()) if isinstance(label_col, pd.DataFrame) else LabelEncoder().fit_transform(label_col)
    rtn_dict = dict()
    if is_need_mapping_table:
        list_value = [e[0] for e in label_col.values] if isinstance(label_col, pd.DataFrame) else [e for e in label_col]
        rtn_dict = dict(zip(nda_rtn_value, list_value))

    if isinstance(label_col, pd.DataFrame):
        nda_rtn_value = nda_rtn_value.reshape(-1, 1)

    return nda_rtn_value, rtn_dict


def import_file() -> pd.DataFrame:

    page_content = textwrap.dedent(  # Remove any common leading whitespace from every line in text.
        """\
        page,Page_Value
        page1,12
        page2,1   
        page3,2   
        page4,3   
        page5,10
        page6,11
        page7,13
        page8,67
        page9,70
        """
    )
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(page_content), header=0)
    return df


def elbow_find_n(x):
    wcss = []
    for i in range(1, 10):
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', random_state=0)
        kmeans.fit(x)
        wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
    plt.plot(range(1, 10), wcss, marker='o')
    plt.title('Elbow graph')
    plt.xlabel('Number of Clusters')
    plt.ylabel('within-cluster sums of squares WCSS')
    plt.show()


def rebuild_df(df, clusters, mapping_table):
    df['clusters'] = clusters
    df.rename(columns={'page': 'page-id'}, inplace=True)
    df['page'] = df.apply(lambda df_: mapping_table[df_['page-id']], axis=1)
    df = df.reindex(['page-id', 'page', 'clusters', 'Page_Value', ], axis=1)
    return df


def visualizing_the_clusters(kmeans: KMeans, df: pd.DataFrame):
    standard_rgb = RGBColor()

    # plt.scatter(df[df.clusters == 0]['page-id'], df[df.clusters == 0]['Page_Value'], s=2, c='red', label='Careful')
    # plt.scatter(df[df.clusters == 2]['page-id'], df[df.clusters == 2]['Page_Value'], s=2, c='cyan', label='Careless')
    # ...
    for color_idx, (cur_set, color) in enumerate(
            zip(set(df.clusters), standard_rgb.get_tuple())
    ):
        contain_cluster_index = df.clusters == cur_set
        plt.scatter(df[contain_cluster_index]['page-id'], df[contain_cluster_index]['Page_Value'],
                    s=2, c=color, label=f'Cluster{cur_set}: {kmeans.cluster_centers_[cur_set][0]}')

    n_cluster = len(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
    plt.scatter(np.ones(n_cluster)*(-1), kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], s=(50/n_cluster), c='purple', label='Centroids')
    plt.title('Page and Page_Value')
    plt.xlabel('Page_ID')
    plt.ylabel('Page_Value')
    plt.legend(loc=(1.05, 0.5))
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output

```
   page-id   page  clusters  Page_Value
0        0  page1         0          12
1        1  page2         2           1
2        2  page3         2           2
3        3  page4         2           3
4        4  page5         0          10
5        5  page6         0          11
6        6  page7         0          13
7        7  page8         1          67
8        8  page9         1          70
Cluster0 = page1,page5,page6,page7
Cluster1 = page8,page9
Cluster2 = page2,page3,page4
{0: ['page1', 'page5', 'page6', 'page7'], 1: ['page8', 'page9'], 2: ['page2', 'page3', 'page4']}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Carson! your code works super. 
1. Can you help me how can I copy this data to clipboard or can save in a dataframe, same o/p like yours
 2. any help for the cluster visualization?

Comment: Hi Carson, I am analyzing the o/p and found that due to label encoding of unique pages I am getting incorrect clusters.This is because cluster formation from your code is not only taking the Page Values however also the numeric values of Pages. This is leading to incorrect combination. The code shared by Son is working fine for me! Thanks

Comment: Good morning @sahay, I update my code.
Update one, I create a new Dataframe that combines all information which lets the user is more clear of data. Update two: visualizing the clusters.

Comment: But I still confused about what you said **incorrect clusters** since my English not well, can you simply tell me, for example, your expected ``Cluster1 = p1,p2,p3`` and I output ``Cluster1=p5`` so that I can understand I wrong?

Comment: Hi Carson, Very good morning!
1. You have used label encoder for Pages, that gives unique values to each pages
2. I wanted to cluster basis on Page Values not on Pages
3. You can compare 2nd part of Son's ode o/p and yours o/p.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215792/discussion-between-sahay-and-carson).